What is an object's "location" exactly (in script and transform panel)?
What is an object's "location"?
In all apps that I'm familiar with, there are straightforward local and global locations. If I move the parent object, the child's local location stays but its global location changes. If I move the child, both its global and local locations change.
But in Blender, the child's "location" remains the same when moving its parent, so it's not global (because the child is moved with parent). But its value doesn't change after changing its parent to another object. So it's not local either. What is it then?
I assume whatever this "location" is, it also applies to "rotation", right? Also, it will have the same usage in python?
Thanks

You can view the transforms (location rotation scale) as deformations. About location, it's also kinda deformation from the origin of the scene. Without any parenting, it's simply the location in global coordinates. But with parenting and such, it's closer to a deformation (or local coordinates as you said). For example if the child should be at the same location as the parent, then location is 0. You have 3 shortcuts to reset location rotation and scale : Alt+G, Alt+R and Alt+S. And no, the object rotation doesn't affect the object location (for one object with no parent).

Official documentation here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.2/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html.

Thanks. But I got what's happening. It has something to do with "keep transform" option when assigning or changing parent. With just shift(+alt) dragging on Scene Collection panel, the location remains unchanged. But if I do it via the context menu or Ctrl+p and make parent without inverse (keep transform), then it becomes the familiar "local" location. I don't understand the point, because the movement hierarchy seems the same in both cases.
